# Can a function end its caller's function?

Tags: java, c, scope

Let's say we have the following two methods:

```
public static void repeat(){
    while (1){
        otherFunc();
    }
}

public static void otherFunc(){
    if (something){
        //Here
    }
}
```

Is there a way for, in the place of `//Here`, to cause a `break` or `return` in the `repeat` function?

Initially, I thought definitely not, because of the issue of scope. Also, if it was intended to be used like that, `otherFunc` could return a `boolean` and be placed in an if-statement to end the while-loop or the method.

However, I could not find anything to prove that it cannot have that behavior.

Is this possible?

Although I wrote this in Java, it would also be helpful to know if this stays true in C-languages also.

Comment: You can throw an exception.  It will travel up the call stack until handled.

Comment: @azurefrog if it's not handled anywhere it may break the application, but it's an alternative.

Comment: can always use a global variable. But thats a bad practice. Other way would be to pass some value to function. Basically its a problem of maintaining the context. You can figure out the method name of caller something like StackTraceElement[] stacktrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
StackTraceElement e = stacktrace[2];//maybe this number needs to be corrected
String methodName = e.getMethodName();

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza True, but it's the only way I can think of to explicitly pass control back up to a calling method apart from `return`ing a value.

Comment: Depending on the case, I would choose between raising an exception or returning a flag value (not necessarily a boolean) to stop the execution of the caller method. There's no bullet-proof answer since it depends on the specific design of each use case.

Comment: @pankajanand18 you're using a bazooka to kill a bug...

Comment: I think the C tag is misplaced here, unless you want to ask about C explicitly. In which case you can call `exit` or even `abort`.

Comment: I don't believe there is any language, other than assembly, where a called subroutine/function/method can change the control flow of its caller (other than by throwing an exception, but the callee can't know how many calling subroutines it will interrupt--or by terminating the whole program or thread).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ROFL :)

Comment: This is theoretical, or course. There are plenty of ways to design the methods so that this would be unnecessary.

Comment: @ajb - Pretty sure that PL/I has a way to exit a method and go back several levels, though I don't recall any details.  And C has `setjmp`/`longjmp`.  If there's a feature that can be conceived of, some language somewhere has done it.

Comment: @HotLicks Right about C, but I was thinking more along the lines of way to say "exit exactly one (or N) callers", as opposed to "exit back to some place without knowing how many callers this exits".  PL/I could have had that, it had some interesting features.  Never used it, though (although I sure wished I could when I was stuck using COBOL way back when...).  Come to think of it, APL might have had a way, but I don't remember one.

Comment: You could handle a global linked list of pointers to `setjmp` jump buffers, if you want to jump, say, 5 functions back, you get back 4 positions in that list and `longjmp` there. The callers have to do the corresponding `setjmp` calls... How theoretical is that question?

Answer (score 1):

if can you change the code, do it like this:

```
public static void repeat()
{
    while (otherFunc()) ;
}

public static boolean otherFunc()
{
    if (something){
         return true;
    }
    //more stuff...
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C you can use [longjmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csetjmp/longjmp/) and [setjmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csetjmp/setjmp/) functions but it is little bit tricky. More reading also on wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setjmp.h